# typo3 menu doesn't work?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I try to let typo3 generate a menu for me but it just doesn't work.

Here is my TypoScript:

```
# Menu
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
  entryLevel = 1
  1 = TMENU
  1 {   
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>

    NO = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

    ACT < .NO
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current_page_item"><b>|</b></li>
  }
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zxEG.jpg) is a Screenshot of my DocumentTree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**entryLevel** : Defines at which level in the rootLine the menu should start.
Default is “0” which gives us a menu of the very first pages on the site.
Reference:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Set `entryLevel` to `0`. EntryLevel 1 only contains a disabled page.

Comment: Additionally try to avoid entrylevel, but use special = directory. Will save you from more hassles.